# Composer library LibraryInstaller install method not call

Tags: package, composer-php, call

I am trying create composer package with installer. I found this tutorial:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md#the-plugin-class

My TemplateInstaller looks like:

```
class TemplateInstaller extends LibraryInstaller {

public function __construct(IOInterface $io, Composer $composer, $type = 'library', Filesystem $filesystem = null, BinaryInstaller $binaryInstaller = null)
{
    echo "\n [INSTALLER CONSTUCTOR]";
    parent::__construct($io, $composer, $type, $filesystem, $binaryInstaller);
}


/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getInstallPath(PackageInterface $package)
{
    echo "\n [GET INSTALL PATH] " . $package->getPrettyName();
    return parent::getInstallPath($package);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function supports($packageType)
{
    echo "\n [SUPPORTS]";
    return TRUE;
}

public function install(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $package) {
    echo "\n [INSTALL]";
    parent::install($repo, $package); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}



public function isInstalled(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $package) {
    echo "[IS INSTALLED ] return false";
    return FALSE;
}


public function uninstall(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $package) {
    echo "\n [UNINSTALL]";
    parent::uninstall($repo, $package); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}

public function update(InstalledRepositoryInterface $repo, PackageInterface $initial, PackageInterface $target) {
    echo "\n [UPDATE]";
    parent::update($repo, $initial, $target); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

When I now install composer package I expect that will be called method install and to console will be output [INSTALL]. Unfortunately install method is not called.

When I use "composer update" after install and in package is new commit, is called TemplateInstaller::update method exactly I expect.

When I remove package from my composer.json and use "composer update" method  TemplateInstaller::uninstall is called as I expect.

Problem is only with call of method TemplateInstaller::install.

Do you know why method TemplateInstaller::install is not called?

Thanks